# Texture of an instanced object is different to the original

Tags: texturing, shaders, geometry-nodes

I want to have the same texture on each plate which is just a cube attached to the four sideways facing sides of each pillar.

I added four plates to the original pillar and duplicated them with the same instance on point setup I used for the pillars, but as you can tell, the texture is really stretched and also different on each pillar.

Therefore, even if I fix the stretching on a single side of only one pillar, it's off on the other sides and also on the other pillars. It's more off the further away the pillar is from the fixed one, like the texture orientates itself with coordinates a not on the object it's applied to.

I tried all the different outputs of the texture coordinate node, but no matter what I tried the texture was always different on each plate.

[image: My instance on points setup]
[image: My shading setup]
[image: Texture applied looks different on each pillar]

Comment: You should definitely not use the generated coordinates, because this remaps the Texture coordinates to the bounds of the mesh, and the bounds of your "all pillars" objects are naturally way bigger than your "single pillar" object, so it's logical the texture is stretched. Have you tried the "Object" output ?

Comment: I tried that already, didn't work unfortunately. I added another picture to show how it looks, when I use the object output.

Comment: UV or Object coordinates should work, but the texture may need to be resized.  You could also try checking 'use instancer' in the texture coordinate node